# How to verify a root of high degree polynomials?

Tags: trapdoor

If I want to verify a root of a  polynomial that has degree $n$, I must to compute the $x^n, x^{n-1}...x, 1$.It seems to be inefficient. Is there any method to do this without computing many power?

Comment: You can compute $\mathrm{gcd}(f(x), x-\alpha)$ where $f$ is your polynomial and $\alpha$ your root. Why do you ask this in cryptography section?

Comment: Are you talking about systems where x*x is a substantially more expensive operation than a*x or x+y  (where a is a scalar, x y are your values).  Intuitively the cost of verifying this way is linear (or at least log-linear if you need a sparse polynomial), and failing to account for any one term in the polynomial would invalidate the verification.

Comment: Instead of explicitly computing powers of $x$, why not use [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method)?

Comment: @corpsfini I want to construct a trapdoor by using the root of a polynomial.

Comment: @corpsfini In this case, wouldn't polynomial division be more efficient?